# how to use materialize component with .net mvc with angular js routing

Tags: angular, routes, components, materialize

Hi I'm using **Materilize** form within angular js.net MVC with Routing of angularjs.  and its  not working . When when we normal use without roting of angular js its working . Then how to use materialize component with mvc with angular js routing .

```
<div class="form-group-material">
<input type="text" name="location" class="input-material">
<label for="location" class="label-material prmx_lable">Location</label>                                    </div>
```